# What is the importance of magnetuc flux cutting the surface of coil

Tags: magnetic-fields, electricity, electromagnetic-induction, vector-fields

Iam a bit confused about magnetic flux lines cutting a coil say if we have a rectangular coil abcd like in the dynamo and the sides ab and cd are perpendicular to the magnetic flux when the plane of the coil is parallel to it, then I read that in such case the magnetic flux cutting the coil is zero. I'm confused about how it is zero although ab and cd are perpendicular to the field, I mean it is not important that the field lines cut the surface of the coil or not as it is already cutting the sides of the coil. I'm saying this because when we calculate the average induced emf we say that if the coil position changed from parallel to perpendicular then the magnetic flux cutting the coil is +BA although it should be negative. Please try to understand me I feel like I'm very confused.

Comment: Are you asking why the flux is zero when the coil is in [this position](https://previews.123rf.com/images/doethion/doethion1312/doethion131200002/24540175-ilustraci%C3%B3n-de-una-dinamo-de-corriente-continua-sencilla.jpg)?

Comment: @Urb yes , I know that it is because it is parallel, but I mean the sides of the coil are perpendicular so what matters if the surface of the coil is perpendicular or not